# Magnific Popup Lightbox works in Ruby on Rails development but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have Magnific Popup installed in my Ruby on Rails (Ruby v2.2.1, Rails v4.1.8) application. The popup works wonderfully locally to zoom in on a single image but when deployed to Heroku just opens the image in the current tab.

Magnific Popup was installed as follows:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'magnific-popup-rails'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shCore
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushBash
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushCss
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushJScript
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushPlain
//= require syntax-highlighter-rails/shBrushRuby
//= require magnific-popup
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss:

```
@import "magnific-popup";
```

And some custom CSS from one of the examples on the Magnific website (below the import in application.css.scss):

```
/* padding-bottom and top for image */
.mfp-no-margins img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0;
}
/* position of shadow behind the image */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
/* padding for main container */
.mfp-no-margins .mfp-container {
    padding: 0;
}

/* 

for zoom animation 
uncomment this part if you haven't added this code anywhere else

*/

.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
        opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
        opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container, 
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I then have a custom JavaScript file named magnific-custom.js in app/assets/javascripts (also code taked from the example on Magnific’s website):

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }

    });

    $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        image: {
            verticalFit: false
        }
    });

    $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        }
    });

});
```

And then for the HTML I have:

```
<p style="text-align:center"><a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/justinvrooman/uploads/article-content-imgs/nitrous-io.png" style="cursor: zoom-in;"><img alt="" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/justinvrooman/uploads/article-content-imgs/nitrous-io.png" style="height:60%; width:60%" /></a></p>
```

Like I said, the Magnific Popup works wonderfully locally in my development environment but once deployed to Heroku it doesn’t work. Some things I have tried include:

1. Tried moving the custom JavaScript into different locations.
2. Compiled assets locally (and deployed to Heroku) using:

   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
3. Made some config changes:

   config.assets.compile = (tried both true and false)

   config.serve_static_assets = (tried both true and false)
4. Checked my page source to look for clues… Nothing.
5. Googled about everything I can think of.

At this point I am at a loss as to what I can try or how I can debug the issue as there is no indication of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( magnific-custom.js )
```

and then:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "magnific-custom" %>
```

Can anyone explain why I had to do this explicitly to get this working?